# PySide2 will not import when built with cx_freeze 6.6

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pyside2, shiboken2

I have a program that is being built with cx_freeze 6.2.
It was working great until we added a GUI and then we started getting ImportErrors after it build the EXE.

```
...
File "C:\Users\Engineer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PySide2\__init__.py", line 88, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Engineer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PySide2\__init__.py", line 54, in _setupQtDirectories
File "C:\Users\Engineer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shiboken2\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
...
```

I have been looking for a solution for a while. Unfortunately the only ones I have found are "use Python 3.6 and cx_freeze 5.1.1" however that is not an option for me as we have a static environment and it will take a lot of effort to get approval to change the version of python. (smaller packages might have more luck)

I have tried new versions of cx_freeze (6.6) but still no luck.

Current Configuration:
Python 3.7.6
PySide 5.15.0
shiboken2 5.15.0

Has anyone been able to find a solution to this, some build script hack or something that does not involve reinstalling a different version of Python?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `shiboken2.pyd` file which appears in `site-packages\shiboken2\shiboken2.pyd` as the code is importing it:

```
shiboken2\__init__.py line 27:
from .shiboken2 import *
```

I didn't know much about `cx_freeze` but according to [their documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/script.html) you 
 should use commands like `--packages=shiboken2` or something else to include the submodules?